# How to solve the error: "No module named psycopg2" (postgreSQL and Django)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am quite new to Django, and this is my first time setting up a Databse. I followed tutorials, and created a virtual environment. In this virtual environment, the package psycopg2 is installed (as you can see in the image below).

[image]

However, when I use the command "python manage.py migrate", the following error appears: "No module named psycopg2". This is strange, because it seems like psycopg2 is installed, and the right virtual environment is linked with PyCharm.

For the record, I checked similar questions on Stack Overflow, and the solution was usually that "pip install psycopg2" was not used. However, I have done this.

Any guidance would be truly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running `python manage.py migrate` in the virtual env at `project1_env`?

Comment: no! I thought that python manage.py should be run in the project folder :), but I will try what you suggested now. If there is a file called manage.py in the virtual environment 

Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: There will not be a `manage.py` file inside the virtualenv folder. You need to activate the virtualenv before running `python manage.py migrate` by first running `.\project1_env\Scripts\activate`

Comment: Thank you so much! That actually worked! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't activate the virtualenv before you did **python manage.py migrate**.

Activate the vitualenv and try again

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize that the virtual environment had to be activated at all times, before running "python manage.py migrate"